# Reference an imported module with string variable

Tags: javascript

I have the following code snippet.

```
import {English as en} from 'languages/en.js'
import {Spanish as es} from 'languages/es.js'

console.log(this.lang) // es
```

I'm trying to call the corresponding imported module using the `this.lang` string. But not sure how I can call that module.

```
window[this.lang]
```

wouldn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried this as well. But didn't work. ^

Comment: Whoops, my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object and look up `lang` in that:

```
  const result = { es, en }[this.lang];
```

Working with the global scope (aka `window`) can get you into real trouble, thats why it is considered an antipattern (and all those ES 6 features, `let`, `const`, `import` enforce that by making "global variables" not leak to the global scope, therefore you can't access them on `window`).

Comment: Any option to reference `{ es, en }` without typing it again? I mean something similar to `window` or `this`

Comment: This answer could work. Seems there isn't any other option.

Comment: @user1012181 oh well, use a building pipeline that only serves the language file needed to the client.

Comment: I'm sorry, what's a building pipeline?

Comment: Programmers use tools that code for them :) (I admit that "building pipeline" was not quite adequate) I was basically thinking of https://webpack.js.org